# why does the Gmail app on iPhone ignore media queries?

Tags: gmail, media-queries, html-email

I'm putting together an email newsletter for a client, and find that more or less every email client and app provides a more or less readable experience (they still need some work) - except for the Gmail app. Once the breakpoint is reached, it should be displaying as one column. But it does not.

I'm not sure why this is. Is there a way to force the app to display the newsletter in desktop mode shrunken down to fit the screen width? Or is there a way to target Gmail with a conditional so that the content will obey the media query?

Related: the litmus tests I've ran don't look anything at all like the result I'm getting on my iPhone. Why is that?

http://codepen.io/sabaeus/pen/ZGQWdZ?editors=100

This is in my document head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
      <title>Title</title>


    </head>
```

And then this is in my body:

```
<body>

  <!-- background table start -->
  <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="background_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!-- end of background table start -->
          <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="display:inline-block;" width="100%"><img src="http://placehold.it/197x41" style="display:block;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="100">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/699x400" style="display:block;">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <!-- hello/quick links -->
          <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="393" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:53px">Hello,
                  <br>
                  <br> Intro text

                </td>

                <td width="230" class="column" style="height:100%;padding:20px;">
                  <span class="h1">Quick Links</span>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">Link 1</a></strong></span>
                  <br> Info for link 1
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>Link 2</strong></span>
                  <br><a href="#" target="_blank">Link</a>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>Link 3</strong></span>
                  <br><a href="">Link</a>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- hello/quick links -->

          <!-- marketing communications -->
          <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <span class="h1">Headline 1</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="148" class="column-img" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:17px">
                <a href="http://www.aegisliving.com/resource-center/rebecca-if-you-need-help-today-you-probably-needed-help-yesterday/" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/148x111" style="display:block;"></a>
              </td>

              <td width="503" class="column-text-1" style="padding:20px"><span style="font-size:18px;display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>Sub head</strong></span>
                  <br>Info info info info info info info info info info info</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- marketing communications -->

          <!-- new print collateral -->
          <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="top-buffer">
                  <span class="h1">Headline 2</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td width="148" class="column-img" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:17px"><img src="http://placehold.it/148x220" style="display:block;"></td>

                <td width="503" class="column-text-1" style="padding:20px"><span style="font-size:18px;display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>Sub head</strong></span>
                  <br> info info info info</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <!-- new print collateral -->

          <!-- advertising -->
          <!-- brand ads -->
          <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="top-buffer">
                  <span class="h1" style="display:inline-block;">Headline 3</span>
                  <br>
                  <span style="font-size:18px;">
                <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding-top:0px;">
                        <span style="font-size:18px;"><strong>Sub head</strong></span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>


        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="350" class="column" style="height:100%;margin-right:131px"><img src="http://placehold.it/246x264" style="min-width:350px; display:block;"></td>

        <td style="height:100%;" width="350" class="column">
          <img src="http://www.placehold.it/267x324" style="min-width:350px; display:block;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- brand ads -->

  <!-- community ads -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:0px;">
          <span style="font-size:18px;"><strong>Sub head</strong></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="350" class="column" style="height:100%;margin-right:131px">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/197x320" style="min-width:350px; display:block">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  info info info info
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>

        <td style="height:100%;" width="350" class="column"><img src="http://placehold.it/212x328" style="min-width:350px;display:block">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding-top:10px">
                  <br> info info info info info
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- community ads -->
  <!-- advertising -->

  <!-- talent acquisition -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">Headline 4</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <!--  <tr>
      <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   -->
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <a href="#" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/668x195" style="width:100%;display:block;"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- text -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <span style="font-size:18px;display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong>Sub head</strong></span>
          <br>Info info info
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- text -->
  <!-- talent acquisition -->

  <!-- new expert advice -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">Headline 5</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span style="display:inline-block;">Info info info</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- 0 -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:46px"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x281" style="width:100%;display:block;"></td>

        <td width="322" class="column" style="padding:20px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">info info</a></strong></span>
          <br>info info info</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- 0 -->

  <!-- 1 -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:46px"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x281" style="width:100%;display:block;"></td>

        <td width="322" class="column" style="padding:20px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">info info</a></strong></span>
          <br>info info info</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- 1 -->

  <!-- 2 -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:46px"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x281" style="width:100%;display:block;"></td>

        <td width="322" class="column" style="padding:20px">
          <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">info info</a></strong><span>
                 <br>
                info info info</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <!-- 3 -->
        <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td width="345" class="column" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:46px"><img src="http://placehold.it/345x281" style="width:100%;display:block;"></td>

              <td width="322" class="column" style="padding:20px;">
                <span style="display:inline-block; padding-bottom:5px;"><strong><a href="#" target="_blank">info info</a></strong></span>
          <br>info info info
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- 3 -->
  <!-- new expert advice -->

  <!-- epic speaker videos -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">Headline 6</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="345" style="height:100%;display:inline-block;margin-right:17px;" class="column"><img src="http://placehold.it/258x154" style="width:100%;display:block;"></td>

        <td width="423" class="column" style="padding:20px;">info info info info info</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- epic speaker videos -->

  <!-- upcoming events -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="top-buffer">
          <span class="h1">Headline 7</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <!-- <tr>
      <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   -->
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <span style="font-size:17px"><strong>
                May is: Physical Fitness Month&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Jewish American Heritage Month</strong></span>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <ul style="line-height: 150%; width: 582px;">

                    <li style="list-style-type:none; padding-left:10px;background-color:#ededed">May 10th - <span style="font-weight:300">Mother’s Day</span> </li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:10px;">May 25th - <span style="font-weight:300">Memorial Day</span> </li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none; padding-left:10px; background-color:#ededed">June 6th - <span style="font-weight:300">D-Day</span></li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:10px;">June 14th - <span style="font-weight:300">Flag Day</span></li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none; padding-left:10px; background-color:#ededed">June 21st - <span style="font-weight:300">Father’s Day</span></li>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none;padding-left:10px;">June 21st - <span style="font-weight:300">Alzheimer’s Association Longest day (click below for details)</span></li>
                  </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- alzheimer's -->
  <table width="699" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100">
          <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://placehold.it/454x174" style="width:100%;display:block;"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- alzheimer's -->

  <!-- prior -->
  <table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="100" style="padding:20px;">
          <span style="display:inline-block;padding-bottom:5px">
                Info info info
                </span>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- prior-->
  <!-- upcoming events -->


  <!-- footer -->
  <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="100%">
          <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body_table">
            <tbody>
              <!-- Spacing -->
              <tr>
                <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
              <!-- Spacing -->
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- end of footer -->

  <!-- end of background table-->
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,700);
body {
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#background_table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%!important;
  line-height: 100%!important;
}

img {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Trebuchet, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height:120%;
  color: #000;
}

table td[class="column"] {
  height: 100px;
  width: 393px;
  padding: 15px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}

table[class="body_table"] {
  width: 699px;
  margin-top: 21px;
}

table span[class="h1"] {
  font-weight:300;
  font-size:35px;
  color:#ff9001;
}

table td[class="top-buffer"] {
  padding-top: 25px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  table[class="body_table"] {
    width: 600px!important;
  }

  table td[class="column"] {
    width: 100%!important;
    display: block!important;
  }
  table span[class="h1"] {
    line-height:110%!important;
    font-size:23px!important;
  }
  *[class="mob-hide"] { display: none !important }
}
```

Comment: Article: http://www.emaildesignreview.com/email-design-best-practice/googles-embarrassing-email-problem-2465/

Either hybrid, or degrade it nicely. Gmail not supporting media-query or declared styles is just the way things are for now.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail app and Gmail web service strips all class and ID styling out of your style tags.  [More Info Here](http://freshinbox.com/blog/gmail-supports-style-sort-of/)

There is an option for some elemental styling in Gmail web service as seen in link above, but other than that you need to do everything inline.  This removes the capabilities of responsive design as you cannot inline media queries.

Your best bet is fluid design(percentage based to fit small or large screen) or a [mobile first hybrid design](http://labs.actionrocket.co/the-hybrid-coding-approach-2) that is essentially designed first for Gmail/Outlook and then uses media queries and style tags to make it work for all other email clients.